# CSS file loading but not working in Django project

Tags: django

I am new to Django, I am working in python 3.5, I linked CSS using Jinja but I am not able to see the CSS style within my HTML file, even thought I am getting 200 status in my network and the CSS file is loaded but the style is not working. Can you help me.

here is my html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>home</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 
   'posts/customstyle.css'%}">

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is the HTML file</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
```

and my CSS file is also within 'static' folder within my project folder. I have tried changing the name but nothing is happening.

All I get in the console is: 
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-CSS.

While my network is pretty healthy and I am getting my files uploaded properly.

Here is what I am getting in console:

[file uploads sucessfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ijC7.png)

[style showing but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLumi.png)

Comment: I am not sure but you should add spaces after "{%" , and before "%}"

Comment: It is not just directly related with template. You should first check your settings.py. Make sure that you are correctly write your STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_URL or STATIC_ROOT  settings. Then check your urls.py. If you are in development you should import something like this +static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) to end of your urlpatterns.

Comment: Do you see the file link in the page source view?

Comment: @isherwood I am able to see the files in source code and it's being uploaded properly, but it's not showing up on the screen.

Comment: @Brkyrn can you please elaborate a little bit since I haven't changed anything in settings files regarding static content.

Comment: I figured it was actually related to content type of css file which I had to change in registry editor.